# How do I read() integers? how do i write() new lines when contains a variable?

Tags: python

I have written the following function to write down random numbers

```
def randomize(min, max, filename, entries):
    filename = open("henlo.txt", "w")
    for i in range(entries):
        variable = random.randint(min, max)
        filename.write(str(variable))
    filename.close()
```

My problem comes with making a function to read/write the numbers.
I need to write out the random numbers on indevidual lines

Answer (score 0):

Next time format the code in the question so it's readable.

Try this,

```py
def randomize(min_, max_, filename, entries):
    with open(filename, "w") as fp:
        fp.write("\n".join(
            (str(random.randint(min_, max_)) for _ in range(entries))
        ))
```